# Como se pronuncia a palavra "recorde"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronúncia, fonemas

Sempre ouço pessoas falarem de diferentes maneiras a palavra "recorde" (aqui no Brasil) que significa "*desempenho excepcional comprovado que supera os anteriores*".

Qual a maneira certa de pronunciar? "Recórde" ou "Récorde"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Recorde* é uma palavra paroxítona e, portanto, a pronúncia é recórde.

Caso ela fosse proparoxítona, seria acentuada e portanto escrita *Récorde* - o que não é o caso.

Comment: Um momentinho: um recorde, com o sentido da palavra inglesa, tem o acento tônico que cai no re. Ré=corde. Só que o acento não se escreve. A palavra é proparoxítona.

Answer (score 2):

A pronúncia da palavra **na linguagem formal** é **"reCORde"**, pois não tem acento. No Brasil, é possível escutar a variação da pronúncia na linguagem informal.

- Você pode verificar as **pronúncias de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui¹: https://forvo.com/pronounce/

1. Pronúncias realizadas de acordo com a linguagem informal e regionalismo de cada pessoa.

Comment: Infelizmente as 4 gravações no site têm a pronúncia paroxítona, seria interessante documentar a variação que você menciona (que me é também bem familiar). Alguns exemplos que talvez você poderia considerar incluir na resposta: https://youtu.be/lrBW30qBLEw?t=11 , https://youtu.be/ZLZm35KHX-8 .

Comment: No caso do site Forvo, as pronúncias são realizadas por nativos das línguas de acordo com o seu país e região. Como as pessoas falam no dia a dia. No Brasil, por exemplo, o R não é pronunciado da mesma forma nos estados de São Paulo ou da Bahia. Seria mais para verificar a variedade de pronúncias.

Comment: @zewill Certo, só que o acento tônico não mudaria.

Comment: Sim. Eu só quis enfatizar a sílaba tônica. Vou escrever de outra forma. Obrigado por avisar que não ficou claro.